# DB2 INCREMENTAL BACKUP RESTORY

Tags: database, db2, database-backups, db2-luw

**We use IBM DB2 10.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2.**

I try to test recovery plan for DB2.

1. I create a new database

*`CREATE DATABASE EAPOTEST AUTOMATIC STORAGE YES ALIAS EAPOBLOB`*

2. Craate BufferPool and Tablespace

*`CREATE BUFFERPOOL "BufferPool32" IMMEDIATE ALL DBPARTITIONNUMS SIZE AUTOMATIC NUMBLOCKPAGES 0 PAGESIZE 32 K`*

```
CREATE REGULAR TABLESPACE "tablespace1"
IN DATABASE PARTITION GROUP "IBMDEFAULTGROUP"
PAGESIZE 32 K
MANAGED BY AUTOMATIC STORAGE
AUTORESIZE YES
EXTENTSIZE 16
PREFETCHSIZE 16
BUFFERPOOL "BufferPool32"
OVERHEAD 10.5
TRANSFERRATE 0.14
DATA TAG NONE
USING STOGROUP "IBMSTOGROUP"
FILE SYSTEM CACHING
```

3. Create 2 simple tables.

*`CREATE TABLE "DB2ADMIN"."ARTIFACT_FILE1" (
"FILE_ID" DECIMAL(10 , 0) NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( 
START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999 NO CYCLE CACHE 20 NO ORDER ),"FILE_TYPE" VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL) 
DATA CAPTURE NONE 
IN "tablespace1" 
COMPRESS NO`*

```
CREATE TABLE "DB2ADMIN"."EA_PACKAGE1" (
"DOSSIER_NUMBER" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
)
DATA CAPTURE NONE 
IN "tablespace1"
COMPRESS NO
```

3. Add one row per table.
4. Enable incremental backup

*`UPDATE DATABASE CONFIGURATION FOR EAPOTEST USING TRACKMOD YES`*

5. Prepare full offline backup.

*`BACKUP DATABASE EAPOTEST TO %DB_PATH_BACKUP% COMPRESS EXCLUDE LOGS WITHOUT PROMPTING`*

6. After that, i have done some changes in the database, and taken the offline incremental backup.

*`BACKUP DATABASE EAPOTEST INCREMENTAL TO %DB_PATH_BACKUP% COMPRESS EXCLUDE LOGS WITHOUT PROMPTING`*

7. Drop database.

*`DROP DATABASE EAPOTEST`*

8. Restory full backup. **Ok.**

*`RESTORE DB EAPOTEST FROM "..." TAKEN AT ... REPLACE HISTORY FILE WITHOUT PROMPTING`*

9. Restory incremental backup.

*`RESTORE DATABASE EAPOTEST INCREMENTAL FROM "..." TAKEN AT ... WITHOUT PROMPTING`*

**The message is: SQL2540W  Восстановление успешно, однако при работе утилиты Database "2539".**

**Dtabese is not accessable!**
When i try to connect:
**SQL1119N SQLSTATE=57019**

**Is this feasible approach for backup and are steps we take to backup and restore adequate?**

Comment: Why shout at us in the title?

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is incorrect. Your first restore should reference the target incremental image.

```
RESTORE DATABASE ... INCREMENTAL FROM "..." TAKEN AT <incremental backup timestamp>
RESTORE DATABASE ... INCREMENTAL FROM "..." TAKEN AT <full backup timestamp>
RESTORE DATABASE ... INCREMENTAL FROM "..." TAKEN AT <incremental backup timestamp>
```

This is explained in great detail [in the manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/t0006070.html).

Comment: In addition, if you are restoring to a database that *already exists* you will need to use the 'REPLACE EXISTING' command line option. Otherwise the 'WITHOUT PROMPTING' on the restore will force a non-zero exit code (i.e. failure).